# Auctex: when an error occurs, I get moved to a .vrb file instead of the main file

Tags: auctex

If I write a LaTeX document with beamer and fragile slides with an error, like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Test}
  Page 1\eia
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and compile with `C-c C-a`, and go to the first error with `C-c <backtick>` (auctex enabled), I am moved to another file `.vrb`. This is extremely annoying : usually I don’t even realize that I’m in another file, start editing, and when saving I realize I’m in the wrong file.

How could I fix this?